# The synchronisaton in my MySql database requires the restart of my Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I have an application that it is used by more than one user through network sharing the same **MySQL** database. So we need that when the one makes changes on the database the other with simple **refresh** can see the changes.

I am working with **EclipseLink** (having the *cache* config as default).
Actually, the second user (wanting to catch changes made by the first user) has to **restart** the application (created by Netbeans).

**UPDATE:**

Here is the configuration in my *persistence.xml*.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably there is some cache in your applicaltion that holds the previus values retrieved from DB - so the sql you are invoking is not going to DB, but returns results from local cache of your app. According to your persistance configuration, look at the documentation how to disable the cache - it is probably on the ORM level.

**from the EclipseLink documentation, how to disable the cache:**

By default EclipseLink enables a shared object cache to cache objects read from the database to avoid repeated database access. If the database is changed directly through JDBC, or by another application or server, the objects in the shared cache will be stale.

EclipseLink offers several mechanism to deal with stale data including:

```
Refreshing
Invalidation
Optimistic locking
Cache coordination
```

The shared cache can also be disabled. This can be done using the EclipseLink persistence unit property:

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Or the JPA 2.0 persistence unit element:

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

Or can be selectively enabled/disabled using the @Cache annotation:

```
@Entity
@Cache(isolation=ISOLATED)
public class Employee {
  ...
}
```

Or the JPA 2.0 @Cacheable annotation:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class Employee {
  ...
}
```

Do not disable the cache by setting the CacheType to None, this can cause object identity issues.

Comment: Is the cache on the other machine that your friend is using also disabled?

Comment: It is an executable installed in both machines